# Changing QProgressbar chunk's color according to a scale

Tags: c++, qt, chunks, qprogressbar

I am trying to change color of a Qprogressbar according to a variable named accuracy which hold values between 0 and 100. So basically if the accuracy is 100 the color should be green and if it is 0 it should become red and I also want it to support the values and colors between. I have write down the following code but it doesn't affect my progress bar's chunk color. Which part of my code is wrong? 
I appreciate any tips and helps :)

```
int G = static_cast<int> (2.5 * accuracy);
int R = 255 - G;
for (G=0, R=0; G<255 && R<255; G++, R++)
{
    ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet("QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: rgb(R, G, 0);}");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: rgb(R, G, 0);}"` : `R` and `G` in this string do not access the variables R and G;

Q&D and untested:

```
QString("QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: rgb(") + QString::number(R) + ", " + QString::number(G) + ", 0);}"
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Do I need to use for loop to update the values as well?

Comment: I don't know the logic of your code, but I would say no. You have the accuracy, calculate the color you want to be used and set it to the progressbar...

Comment: Thanks, I have accepted your answer and post the final solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

As user1810087 answered, this is the final code I used in case anyone else wants to to the same thing :)

```
void MainWindow:: on_progressBar_valueChanged(int value)
{
    G = static_cast<int>( 2.55 * value );
    R = 255 - G;
    QString Style = QString("QProgressBar::chunk {background-color: rgb(" +QString::number(R) + ", " + QString::number(G) + ", 0);}");
    ui->progressBar->setStyleSheet(Style);
}
```